# WinAPI deprecation after Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8.1

I have been using [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it *failed* in machine which runs with Windows 8.1. After looking some information found out that `GetVersionEx` is depracated since 8.1 version.

I want to ask where could I find full list of deprecated APIs because I don't want to use it anymore.

**EDIT:** I'm not asking what to use instead of `GetVersionEx`, I'm asking for a full list of deprecated APIs.

Comment: Failed how? Deprecated should not mean broken.

Comment: Microsoft writes: "_GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the [Version Helper APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx)_". I suggest, you take a look at those.

Comment: @CoryNelson it returned wrong version.

Comment: This is a very common question, type "windows 8.1 version number" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Comment: @Hans I see that but my question is not about version APIs but about deprecation, I'm looking if something else is not deprecated.

Comment: My answer was deleted by a moderator, but the complete list of compatibility changes including changes to the Windows server and desktop API is here: [Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 client and server compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Just search the SDK headers for `_DEPRECATE`.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has described the changes in [Operating system version changes in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). On the left of the article you can navigate to other issues related to [Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 client and server compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn323743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The behavior you experience is the following:

> In Windows 8.1, the GetVersion(Ex) APIs have been deprecated. That means that while you can still call the APIs, if your app does not specifically target Windows 8.1, you will get Windows 8 versioning (6.2.0.0).

Comment: So do you say, that windows added some new stuff in Windows 8.1 and only `GetVersion(Ex)` became deprecated?

Comment: I say that you can read about all the changes from 8.0 to 8.1 related to compatibility (including the change to `GetVersionEx`) by following the provided link.

Comment: I understand that, but your answer do not answer to my question, it just adds some info about `GetVersion(Ex)` API.

Comment: @ST3: the linked page describes all incompatibilities in Windows 8.1 - if that's the only API it lists then perhaps that's the only API that's deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Somebody on another forum pointed me to this approach.

**Include your Windows 8.1 OS GUID in your application Manifest file**

your .manifest should include Windows 8.1. and look like this.

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
   <application>
     <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8.1 functionality-->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>

</application>
```

One issue with this approach is that your old binaries will always show the wrong Windows version on Windows 8.1 and later Windows Version.

another issue with this approach is that the [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API is still deprecated so you will be not able to target Visual Studio 2013 Platform Toolset. You must set your Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2012 or below.

Update: Actually I remembered you can disable that using something like this.

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)    
versionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);
POSVERSIONINFO pVersionInfo = (POSVERSIONINFO)&versionInfo;
if (::GetVersionEx(pVersionInfo))
{
    if (6 == versionInfo.dwMajorVersion && 3 == versionInfo.dwMinorVersion)
    {
        wcout << _T("Windows 8.1 Detected") << endl;
    }
    else if (6 == versionInfo.dwMajorVersion && 2 == versionInfo.dwMinorVersion)
    {
        wcout << _T("Windows 8.0 Detected") << endl;
    }       
}
#pragma warning (default : 4996)
```

you could use a NetWkstaGetInfo API to get local machine's Version as well.

```
bool GetWindowsVersion(DWORD& major, DWORD& minor)
{   
    LPBYTE pinfoRawData;
    if (NERR_Success == NetWkstaGetInfo(NULL, 100, &pinfoRawData))
    {
        WKSTA_INFO_100 * pworkstationInfo = (WKSTA_INFO_100 *)pinfoRawData;
        major = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_major;
        minor = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_minor;
        ::NetApiBufferFree(pinfoRawData);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    DWORD major = 0;
    DWORD minor = 0;
    if (GetWindowsVersion(major, minor))
    {
        wcout << _T("Major:") << major << _T("Minor:") << minor << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

All that Said I have written two code samples to get Windows Version Without using GetVersionEx or GetVersion APIs. I have posted them on the bottom of the page.
The issue is GetVersionEx API takes only about 10 Micro Seconds to Execute while my code samples take upward of 10-50 milliseconds to execute.

[Getting Windows Version VerifyVersionInfo API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678606/Part1-Overcoming-Windows-8-1s-deprecation-of-GetVe)

Comment: How would you use this from C# without a manifest?  It doesn't have a clue what `DWORD`, `_TCHAR`, `LPBYTE`, `NERR_Success`, `WKSTA_INFO_100`, and those `<<` and `->` and `::` are.

Answer (score 0):

Concur with others on this. if you are starting from scratch the trouble to support TCHAR is not worth it in most cases. If you are building a brand new application you want it to work smoothly at the very least with UTF16 strings (like .NET and java do).
Practicality point 1:
You are not going build multiple versions of your app based on what encoding pre-processor is defined. it was really hard enough to support x64 vs X86 fork of builds.
Practicality point 2:
Overwhelming majority of Windows Apis actually default to W edition of API. for example calling SetWindowTextA will simply eventually call the same implementation as SetWindowTextW