# Windows 10 VersionHelper.h

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to store the version of Windows running on the client computer in a variable. I'm having problems with **VersionHelper.h**, machines that are using **Windows 10** appears as **Windows 8**, how do I fix this?

I'm using Visual Studio **2015**, Target Platform Version: **10.0.10586.0**

```
if (IsWindows7SP1OrGreater())
{
    strcpy_s(this->OS_Detect, "Windows 7 SP1");
}

if (IsWindows8OrGreater())
{
    strcpy_s(this->OS_Detect, "Windows 8");
}

if (IsWindows8Point1OrGreater())
{
    strcpy_s(this->OS_Detect, "Windows 8.1");
}

if (IsWindows10OrGreater())
{
    strcpy_s(this->OS_Detect, "Windows 10");
}
```

**return** of machines with windows 10 = "Windows 8"

Comment: This is by design. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx All versions of Windows starting from 8.1 will appear as 8 - possibly in an attempt to prevent version-specific behavior. [This page gives an ugly work-around.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Either way, it's a dick move on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinAPI deprecation after Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518670/winapi-deprecation-after-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include **`<compatibility>`** flags in application manifest file

See also 
[Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/dn481241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you do not already have a manifest file, use Notepad to create a file called "appname.exe.manifest"

Add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!-- Windows 7 -->
    </application>
  </compatibility>

</assembly>
```

Next, drag and drop this file in to your Visual Studio 2015 project.

For older VS versions you have to specify filename in project -> Manifest section

Comment: This behavior was introduced by Microsoft so a program was not told about versions it didn't know about.